# Change HTML button text that has no ID using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui

I'm working on a project where I have to change the text inside a button, but the button is not allowed to have an ID. I'm wondering how to accomplish this.
If it helps, I am using Kendo UI, which I believe is how the button is given its onClick method using data-bind:

```
<button class="some-css-classes" data-bind="click: myJavascriptFunction">Text I want to change</button>
```

Comment: When and where you want to change the text? At the page load? On a button click? Somewhere else? Do you know the text to change?

Comment: The javascript in the background loads some elements on the page. I want to change the text at various stages in the loading process.

Comment: Does the HTML need to be just like that or could you change it as long as it doesn't have an ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid adding more attributes by just targeting the existing `data-bind` attribute and change the text inside like this:

```
var x = document.querySelector('[data-bind="click: myJavascriptFunction"]');

x.innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

**jsFidldle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/z7t31psn/1/

---

Or if you don't want to create an extra variable:

```
document.querySelector('[data-bind="click: myJavascriptFunction"]').innerHTML = "Hello World";
```

**jsFidldle:** http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/z7t31psn/2/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I like this solution the best as it uses the data-bind attribute, which will be unique for this button, rather than the classes which could be applied to any UI element.

Answer (score 1):

One workaround might be using a `data-id` attribute.

`<button data-id="unique_id">Text I want to change</button>`

and then

`document.querySelector('[data-id=unique_id]').innerHTML = 'something';`

or

`$("[data-id=unique_id]").html('something')`

if you're using jquery

Comment: The OP didn't specify `jQuery` in his question. Please change the approach to a Javascript approach and I'll retract my downvote.

Comment: Vote retracted and +1. Cheers mate!!

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByClassName("class1 class2 class3")[0].innerHTML = "test"` replace zero with the appropriate index. This may require updating if the website markup is modified.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by a class

```
<button class="test">
Test Button
</button>

document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0].innerHTML="Text Changed"
```